# The column sum of symmetric matrix inverse?

Tags: matrix-inverse

Given a symmetric matrix L, and the inverse of L is difficult to solve. Is there any other way to calculate the sum(   inverse(L)(:,i)  ) ?

Comment: Why do you require that result?

Comment: The matrix is always high dimensional, i do not need the whole  inverse matrix, just the column sum of the inverse matrix, so i want to find a method to calculate it quickly!

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that

```
sum ( inverse(L)(:,i) ) = x(i)
```

where the vector `x` is the solution to the simultaneous equations

```
L x = (1,1,...,1)'
```

(`'` denotes transposition). Since solving a system of linear equations is much faster than inverting a matrix `(O(n²)` vs `O(n log(n)))`, this should improve the speed of the computation.